# How to plot two lines (group of rows) in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, row

I Have data of 80 line and 210 columns.

Here i plot one line

```
ggplot(data=Data[c(1:5),], aes(x=x_lab, y=col1, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() + ggtitle("plot of col1 ")
```

[image]

Can you tell me please how i can plot also the rows from 6 to 10 of col1
in other line (like i did for rows 1:5) and in other color
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While with smaller datasets it's tempting to do `geom_line(data=...)` for each separate line, this scales poorly. Since `ggplot2` benefits from having its data in a "long" format, I suggest you reshape it (`reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::pivot_longer`) and then plot.

Lacking your data, I think these will work:

```r
library(ggplot2)

### pick one of these two
longData <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Data, -x_lab, names_to = "variable", values_to = "y")
longData <- reshape2::melt(Data, "x_lab", variable.name = "variable", value.name = "y")

### plot all at once
ggplot(longData, aes(x_lab, y = y, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

(I find it often useful to use `group=variable, color=variable` for more visual breakout of the lines.)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be to add a grouping variable directly to your data if you are only hoping to plot these 10 lines.

```
Data$group <- rep("group1", "group2", each =5)
ggplot(Data, aes(x,y)) +
geom_line(aes(color = group))
```